# How can I use libvlc in c# to tell the duration of an audio file without playing it?

Tags: c#, libvlc

I'm using libvlc in a .netcore project to simply play .ogg and .wav files like this:

```
using Vlc.DotNet.Core;
...

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            string vlcPath;

            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\VideoLAN\VLC"))
              vlcPath = key.GetValue("InstallDir").ToString();

            vlcPlayer = new VlcMediaPlayer(new DirectoryInfo(vlcPath));
            vlcPlayer.Play(songFilename);
            ...
```

I would think doing something like `vlcPlayer.SetMedia(songFilename)` before using the `.Play()` method, would set the `vlcPlayer` object members with info relevant to the clip, but it doesn't. Is there an uncomplicated way to get duration using this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I needed to use the `.Parse()` method after setting the player's media item like this:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(songFilename);
vlcPlayer.SetMedia(info);
vlcPlayer.Parse();
```

But, it appears there is a bug in the latest `Vlc.DotNet.Core` (v3.1.0), such that the `.Parse ()` method does not work as it should. For one, there is no class member to find out the state of the parsing operation, and it never seems to complete if I take a look at the Duration property, which never changes from -1.

Instead, I found `LibVLCSharp` that works great. Here's the code that worked for me that allowed me to work with the media item outside of a player object altogether:

```
var media = new Media(libvlc, new Uri(songFilename));
media.Parse();
while (media.ParsedStatus != MediaParsedStatus.Done) Thread.Sleep(10);
```

Afterwards, `media.Duration` is correct.

Comment: Media has a parse changed event, which allows you to remove that Thread.Sleep code.